# Multiple domains on network - problems with DFS

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller, dfs

I've inherited a setup that we've been running with for a number of years that I've finally decided to sort out.

We have two offices connected via a VPN tunnel.  Office A uses domain.net and office B uses domain.com.  Each office has it's own DC setups and its own DFS servers.

Accessing a server in office A from Office B requires using the fully qualified name of server.domain.net and these servers are set up as A records in a forward lookup zone on the DC.

There is absolutely no legitimate reason to have two different domains, but given that office A is a data centre, the pain in making these changes to a production environment is not a workable solution.

I would like to create a DFS root that can be accessed from either site using the same name.  For example, \\domain.com\dfsroot\documents should resolve to the same network location.

I'm simply not sure where to start with this and would appreciate some guidance.

If you need any more information, I'm happy to provide whatever is required.

Comment: Are these domains in different forests?

Comment: No. Under "Active Directory Domains and Trusts" I have a single domain entry